# Prevent Webpack from dropping my unused code

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-5

For example, my javascript file contains function that's only called when I press HTML button. As far as I know, Webpack will treat the function as a 'dead code' because it isn't used anywhere in javascript file and then dropped the code.

So, the question is how can I disable Webpack from dropping the dead code? (or any other way would also helpful)

For more information, I tried following this thread but still can't figure out how:
[How to prevent unused code from being dropped during webpack build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65221143/how-to-prevent-unused-code-from-being-dropped-during-webpack-build)

What I also already did was exporting everything inside index.js and import them in `main.js` along with other things like jquery and mathjs which then be compiled by Webpack. The output file has `jquery`, `mathjs`, and only `console.log` from `main.js` and `general.js`.

Even when I set the mode in `development` or `none`, the output file doesn't work at all.

```
// package.json

{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "uglify-js": "^3.17.4",
    "uglifyjs-folder": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "mathjs": "^11.5.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js` (though I don't think there's problem here):

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = [
    {
        mode: 'production',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /.html$/i,
                    loader: "html-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /.s?css$/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
                },
            ],
        },
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [...,new CssMinimizerPlugin()]
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: 'index.php'
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
            }),
        ],
    },
]
```

Here's some part of the javascript file:

```
// main.js

import 'jquery';
import { evaluate } from 'mathjs';
console.log(evaluate('2+3'));
import js from './general.js';
```

```
// general.js

export let result;
export function clr() {
    $('.input').text('0');
    $('.result').text('0').removeClass('visible');
    $('.input').addClass('highlight');
    $('.result').removeClass('highlight');
    return result = 0;
}
...
console.log('javascript loaded');
```

```
// output.js 
// (...last part of the code, just to show that the javascript files are compiled successfully)

.......ImmutableDenseMatrix:Eb,Index:Ab,Spa:$b,Unit:Gb,SymbolNode:kN,FunctionNode:zN,Help:UN,Parser:GN}),FN.createProxy(hN),console.log("javascript loaded"),console.log($N("2+3"))})()})();
```

(I'm sorry if I can't explain it well. If there's something that I missing please let me know)

Comment: This is enabled by `mode: 'production'` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/#usage) and `TerserPlugin` in particular (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/). This feature is called Tree Shaking. You disable it by setting the `minimize` option to `false` in the `TerserPlugin` configuration.

Comment: Possible solution move away from inline event handlers if that is how you are calling it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
@SergiuParaschiv I know that I'm in production mode and by that, Webpack does the minify and optimize but I still want Webpack to do all of that so I don't want to disable the minize option. I'm just wondering if there's an option to  prevent Webpack from dropping the dead code.

Comment: I think I'll try what @epascarello suggested for now. Thank you also for telling me. I can't believe that I forgot I can just do the event handler inside javascript.